# Sharepoint ListView with content types problem

Tags: sharepoint

I have a custom asp.net form that I want to place a ListView control in it.

The ListView displays items from a list that has three content types.

I provide the ListID and the ViweId to the listView but I receive the following error:

```
Cannot complete this action.

Please try again.   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetFolderContentTypeId(String bstrUrl, String bstrFolderUrl, Object& pvarContentTypeId) 
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetFolderContentTypeId(String bstrUrl, String bstrFolderUrl, Object& pvarContentTypeId)
```

The ListView works normally if I displayed items from a list with only one content type.

I believe it has something to do with the content types.

what can be the solution for this ?

thanks

Comment: Perhaps you should add more code to the question, such as the aspx code